# Find and replace a specific capturing group regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings of the form:

`ae n d <> ih t <> ih z <> w er th <> m eh n sh ax n <> ih n <> p ae s ih ng <> dh ae t <,> ae z <> ae n <> ih g z ae m p ax l <> ah v <> f ay n <> t ax p aa g r ax f iy <,>`

Where this sentence says 'And it is worth mention in passing that, as an example of fine typography'

I have another set of files of the form:

```
4
6
```

Which means that I need to replace the string above with

```
ae n d <> ih t <> ih z <> w er th <> | m eh n sh ax n <> ih n <> p ae s ih ng <> dh ae t <,> ae z <> ae n <> | ih g z ae m p ax l <> ah v <> f ay n <> t ax p aa g r ax f iy <,>
```

Where the 4th and 6th `<>` have been replaced with `<> |`

So far I have captured all the groups with this regex:

```
break_match = re.compile("[<]?.[>]+")
for match in re.finditer(break_match, sentence_match):
    match_group = match.group(0)
```

But I'm not sure how to iterate over the captured groups (because it does it in one go), and then replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `re.sub`. The `repl` argument can be a function, which gets called for every non-overlapping match (taking a match object as its one argument and returning the string to substitute in). So you can use a class to track state and pass in a member function to do (or not do) the replacement as desired.

A quick and dirty example might look like:

```
class WordCount(object):
    def __init__(self, counts):
        self.counts = counts
        self.cur_count = counts.pop(0) if counts else None

    def replace_word_break(self, match):
        if self.cur_count is None:
            # we're done; don't replace anything else
            return match.group(0)
        self.cur_count -= 1
        if self.cur_count:
            # haven't reached the next break; don't replace
            return match.group(0)
        # we've reached a break; figure out next count and replace
        self.cur_count = self.counts.pop(0) if self.counts else None
        return "{} |".format(match.group(0))

word_counter = WordCount([4, 6])
result = break_match.sub(word_counter.replace_word_break, sentence_match)
```